# connecting to sqlite database for standalone executable

Tags: javafx, netbeans, sqlite

Well, I have a sqlite database called test.db in under src. I have modified build-impl to copy "test.db" to dist directory in "-post-build" . It does that correctly. 
This is how I have coded in conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/test.db");

Build works fine, build-impl copies fine. But when I run the program from Netbeans, the udpates go to src/test.db instead of dist/test.db. Is this correct way of coding. Because this jar file and the database file will be in a standalone machine, with no netbeans.

Am I approaching this correctly ? My sqlite version is 3.xx.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys.... this works fine, when I run the Jar file from a standalone mode and not thru Netbeans. When I run from netbeans the updates go to test.db in src directory... but when I run from explorer test.db in dist directory is updated. !!!!!